# Nbconvert: How to change font of code cells in the output pdf/html?

Tags: python, fonts, jupyter-notebook, jinja2, nbconvert

I'm using nbconvert to convert a jupyter notebook file to html and/or pdf. With the below custom template, the Markdown text in the jupyter notebook is all Arial; however, the text created from code cells with print statements is a different font. How do I change the font of the output text from, for example, `print("This is my code")` to also be Ariel? In the below code, I'm trying to just make all of the text Arial.

My index.html.j2

```
{%- extends 'lab/index.html.j2' -%}

{%- block html_head_css -%}
  {{ super() }}
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
    }
    h1, h2, h3 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .header {
      overflow: hidden;
      # background-color: #f1f1f1;
      # padding: 20px 10px;
    }
    .logo-container {
      # margin: auto;
      # width: fit-content;
      text-align:left;
      width:50px;
    }
    body {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
{%- endblock html_head_css -%}

{% block body_header %}
  <body class="jp-Notebook theme-light" style="padding: 0; margin: 0;">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo-container width:50px;">
    <img src="myimage.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding: 20px; margin: 20px;">
{% endblock body_header %}

{% block body_footer %}
  </div>
  </body>
{% endblock body_footer %}
```

[image: The top line is a markdown cell and the second line is a output of a print statement]

Answer (score 0):

I just added the below, and it is working now.

```
* {
   font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: This is unclear. Where was this added?